# Import error when pipelining data from spider into sqlalchemy table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

This is what the project tree looks like:

```
rym_chart_scraper
├───scrapy.cfg
├───rym_chart_scraper
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───items.py
│   ├───models.py
    ├───pipelines.py
    ├───settings.py
    ├───spiders
        ├───my_spider.py
        ├───__init__.py
```

pipelines.py

```
from models import TopAlbums, db_connect, create_topalbums_table
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


class TopAlbumPipeline:
    def __init__(self):
        engine = db_connect()
        create_topalbums_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        topalbums = TopAlbums(**item)

        try:
            session.add(topalbums)
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()

        return item
```

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime

import settings

Base = declarative_base()


def db_connect():
    return create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))


def create_topalbums_table(engine):
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


class TopAlbums(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'top_albums'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Artist = Column('Artist', String)
    Album = Column('Album', String)
    Chart_year = Column('Chart_year', String)
    Genre = Column('Genre', String)
    Ratings = Column('Ratings', Integer)
    Reviews = Column('Reviews', Integer)
    Date = Column('Date', DateTime)
```

And the spider:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from rym_chart_scraper.utility import find_between, listToString
from rym_chart_scraper.items import TopAlbumChartItem
from datetime import datetime


class TopAlbumChartSpider(Spider):
    name = "top_music_charts"
    allowed_domains = ['rateyourmusic.com']

    start_urls = [
        "https://rateyourmusic.com/charts/top/album/all-time"
    ]

    n_pages = 1

    def parse(self, response):

        for album, stats in zip(response.css('div.chart_main'),
                                response.css('div.chart_stats')):
            ... 

            yield item

        next_page = response.css('a.navlinknext')[0].css(
            'a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
            self.n_pages += 1
            if self.n_pages < 31:
                yield Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

When I run the scraper with:

```
scrapy crawl top_music_charts
```

I get the following import error.

```
2016-12-11 17:46:41 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 72, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 97, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 58, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
    mwcls = load_object(clspath)
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 44, in load_object
    mod = import_module(module)
  File "/Users/baasman/anaconda/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/baasman/Documents/python-workspace/rym_chart_scraper/rym_chart_scraper/pipelines.py", line 1, in <module>
    from models import TopAlbums, db_connect, create_topalbums_table
ImportError: No module named 'models'
```

Trying to import 'models' interactively from **main** doesn't give an error, just when running the actual spider from the command line. Is there something wrong with the structure of the project? Or is it some other silly mistake? For some reason I can not get past this.

Comment: did you create the scrapy project with [`scrapy startproject myproject`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#creating-a-project)?

Comment: Yes, I added the models.py there myself though, as I saw someone do in tutorial: http://newcoder.io/scrape/part-3/. I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation though.

Comment: what about `from rym_chart_scraper.models ...`

Comment: Great, that actually does import the model module but but now fails to import settings, which is interesting because I was able to import them fine before adding the item pipeline.

Comment: do the same `from rym_chart_scraper import settings`, or better just import the ones you need

Comment: Thanks @eLRuLL, that got it to work. Still not really sure why i was able to get it to work before I added the models.